# how to change active wifi connetion on mac OS X from terminal

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

I need to do changing the active WiFi connection on mac OS X from terminal. For example, I have two available WiFi hot-spots: WIFI1 and WIFI2 (and I already been connected to both of them so passwords already stored on system). Now I connected to WIFI1. How can i switch to WIFI2 using only terminal commands?

Answer (score 1):

i found a decision

networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI2 WIFI2_PASSWORD

that is working for me